# cookies and session in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, session, cookies

I want to set session and store values like cookies in the web browser in iPhone App. Is it possible? How can I implement this in iPhone? Can any one suggest a good solution..

Answer (score 1):

Just set cookies like

```
 NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
 NSHTTPCookie* testCookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  @"1", NSHTTPCookieValue,
  @"test_cookie", NSHTTPCookieName,
  @".facebook.com", NSHTTPCookieDomain,
  @"/", NSHTTPCookiePath,
  nil]];
  [cookies setCookie:testCookie];
```

And Get the cookies like

```
 NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {
        //here you can get you specific cookies
    }
```